# Quick question on inequality

Tags: calculus, inequality

For constants $C_1,C_2>0$, is it true that$$
C_1-C_2x^\alpha\leq C(1-x)^\alpha
$$
for some constant $C>0$? Thank you.

Comment: What is $\alpha$? In particular, is it positive? Is it an integer? Otherwise, one must be a bit careful about what you mean when you write $(1-x)^\alpha$ when $x > 1$. Relatedly, what is the range for $x$?

Comment: $x$ and $\alpha$ are both real and positive. I guess the answer is in general no.

Comment: Indeed, it's not even clear what you mean by this inequality when $x > 1$.